# How to get iPhone or iPad access to Public Folders? (especially Contacts)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, iphone, public-folders, ipad

I have a bunch of users who need access to the Exchange 2003 Public Folders and contacts.

What options do we have to give them access?  Is offline access available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for viewing Public Folders via (Over the Web) Exchange Active Sync in 2003 or 2007.

There are third party applications that allow you to do this, but it is not a native capability of the iPhone at this time.

Comment: There is a product that looks as though it may do what you need, but it may not work the way you want it to.  http://www.somebytes.net/27-1-OLMixedFolders.html

Comment: Do you know if Safari works?